# How do I drive engagement on a question?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question that got a fair number of upvotes, but no answers. It seems to be disappearing off the front page, so I think I probably won't get an answer at this point. Is there a way to drive engagement besides offering a bounty?

I'm talking about [this question](https://materials.stackexchange.com/q/129/97) if the specifics matter at all.

Comment: I reached out several times to Ramis Movassagh to answer this question, and he replied saying that he uses a different definition of ergodicity, and he provided a link to his recent arXiv paper on the topic. He was at first reluctant to join the site, but he eventually did. When he did, he answered your sign-problem question and not this one, so I have reached the end of my rope. I would listen to Tyberius and advertise it by posting it on FB groups and subreddits: This will also bring in more users.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple ways you can go about this.

1. Comment/edit your post: The default on the homepage is to list questions in order of most recent activity. If other people have engaged with your post earlier or you have some new insight, edit your post to share that point and explain why it hasn't answered your question. Your research or other users post might have even led you to an additional question, which you can link to your initial one. However, don't make trivial edits or unrelated links in new posts just to bump your question.
2. Advertise (broad): The site is still pretty young, so the best person to answer your question may not be using the site yet. There are [Facebook groups](https://www.facebook.com/groups/MaterialsModelingStackExchange), [subreddits](https://www.reddit.com/r/comp_chem/), and other forums where you might be able to attract users here by pointing out this question to them.
3. Advertise (narrow): If your question came about from studying a particular paper/book, perhaps contact the author(s) and point them to the question. If you are having that problem, others likely are as well. It would be much easier for the author(s) to address these questions in a public forum than in a bunch of separate, private emails.
4. Bounty: I know you mentioned besides bounties, but this a great way to get a post attention. One concern you might have is that you are guaranteed to lose rep, but aren't guaranteed an answer. Other SE sites have gotten around this issue by having essentially a ["Bounty Board"](https://materials.meta.stackexchange.com/q/109/7) on the Meta site (which I have just started here), where you can highlight a question and only officially activate the bounty once an answer has come in.